# Gembox Spreadsheet C#: It is a way to detect if a cell has border?

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

As we know, in Gembox Spreadsheet, you can set a border (with C# language) for a cell like:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Style.Borders.SetBorders(MultipleBorders.All, Color.FromArgb(252, 1, 1), LineStyle.Thin);
```

It is a way to check if a cell contains border (bottom or top border) ?

**Update**

I found the solution with Gembox support:

```
var hasLeftBorder = cell.Style.Borders[IndividualBorder.Left].LineStyle != LineStyle.None;
```

Comment: Check the `Gembox` API for equivalent to `.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone`

Comment: I didn't found any trick related to what you wrote

Comment: I just wanted to add that if your `hasLeftBorder` is `true`, then the cell on its right side will have `IndividualBorder.Right `. However, if you want to find out which cell has that border directly defined on it, then you can use [`GetUnresolvedBorder`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/M_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellBorders_GetUnresolvedBorder.htm) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [on the Gembox Spreadsheet documentation page for the `CellBorder` class](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellBorder.htm). There are 2 properties on the `CellBorder` class: `LineColor` & [`LineStyle`](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellBorder_LineStyle.htm) -  use the getter property of the `LineStyle` and compare it to a [`LineStyle` enumeration](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_LineStyle.htm)

Comment: I mailed the GemBox support and they suggested me to do: see my edited question.